# Is it okay to use one RabbitMQ channel for all goroutines?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp, channel, goroutine

I'm doing a message publisher and a receiver to/from rabbitmq queue.
I'm planning to use one rabbitmq channel for publishing messages and one for fetching, but i also want my code to be asynchronous, is it the right way to use one rabbitmq channel per multiple goroutines?

Comment: Channels are used to communicate between goroutines. They don't make sense in a single goroutine. So yes, of course that's okay.

Comment: @Peter i'm not about golang channels, but about rabbitmq channels

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a golang-guy, by I use every day RabbitMq with .Net driver; .Net driver *channels* (an abstraction that encapsulate interactions with queue/exchange and message publishing/subscribing) are very similar to golang RabbitMq *channels*, so I think my answer can help you.
While *connections* are *tread safe* by design and are supposed to be shared between threads, *channels* are not: so, if different aysnchronous goroutines can be run in different threads (this is up to you: I don't known how golang runtime works) you should not share the same channel instance between them.
I hope this can help you.